# Select de mi base de datos está devolviendo los valores duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy realizando una consulta a mi base de datos mediante `select`. Según el código de abajo no aparecen mensajes de errores, pero está duplicando las filas de la tabla. Intenté cambiar el código del `select` dejándolo sin el `INNER JOIN` pero no funciona de la manera que necesito.

Código PHP y HTML:

```
  <table class="table table-striped">

    <tr>
      <th>ID quarto</th>
      <th>Hotel</th>
      <th>Tipo de quarto</th>
      <th>Numero do quarto</th>
      <th>Valor diaria R$</th>

    </tr>
    <?php

    $sql= "SELECT  id_tipo_quarto,  num_quarto, valor_diaria,
                  nome_hotel, tipo_quarto2
                  FROM tipo_quarto 
                  INNER JOIN hoteis_pousadas  
                  INNER JOIN tipo2 ON cod_tipo2 =  tipo_quarto ";
    $resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);
  while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
      echo '
      <tr>
      <td>'.$row['id_tipo_quarto'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['nome_hotel'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['tipo_quarto2'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['num_quarto'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['valor_diaria'].'</td>

      </tr>


      ';
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Éste es el resultado que obtengo con los valores duplicados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El primer inner join no especifica ningún campo, ¿podría eso estar causando algún problema con el select?

Comment: @ Alvaro Montoro no parece ser esso, por que en el select antes del from ya estoy diciendo qual campo del primer inner join tiene que aparecer que es el campo nome_hotel. Tente Cambiar pero quando hago cualquier  cambio no aparece la tabla.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que realmente no se están duplicando las filas (si te fijas en la captura de pantalla, el nombre del hotel es diferente), y entonces esto se puede deber a que, como no estás indicando el `on` en el `inner join` entre `tipo_quarto` y `hoteis_pousadas`, se está haciendo un join completo con todas las filas de una y otra (que no debería ser el caso porque un cuarto va a estar únicamente en un hotel). Si crees que no es por eso, por favor añade la estructura de las tablas y algunos datos (o un enlace a SQLFiddle) donde podamos ver el problema con más detalle.

Comment: @ Alvaro Montoro . Oye cambie como tu orientación y consegui resolver el problema, le añadi  de esta forma (on id_hotel = cod_hoteis_pousada).

Comment: Jejeje... escribí una respuesta 30 segundos antes de tu comentario :P

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro jajaja...Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es que se estén duplicando las filas (si te fijas, realmente no se están duplicando porque los hoteles no son los mismos).

El problema real es que no estás indicando sobre que campo se debe hacer el primer `INNER JOIN` (entre las tablas `tipo_quarto` y `hoteis_pousadas`), y entonces se van a combinar todas las filas de la primera tabla con todas las filas de la segunda tabla sin restricciones.

No lo pones en la pregunta, pero me imagino que en la tabla `tipo_quarto` hay una clave foránea apuntando a `hoteis_pousadas`. Entonces lo que debes hacer es añadir un `ON` que una los campos relacionados de ambas tablas. Algo como esto:

```sql
SELECT id_tipo_quarto, num_quarto, valor_diaria, nome_hotel, tipo_quarto2
FROM tipo_quarto 
     INNER JOIN hoteis_pousadas ON cod_hoteis_pousadas = hoteis_pousada_id
                             -- ^ algo como esto es lo que le falta al código
     INNER JOIN tipo2 ON cod_tipo2 = tipo_quarto;
```

[He creado un pequeño snippet en SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ccc4e/4) que sigue (más o menos) el esquema que indicas en la pregunta y donde puedes ver la diferencia entre poner el `ON` y no ponerlo. En la consulta en la que no está el `ON` se devuelven el doble de resultados porque se están combinando todas las habitaciones con todos los hoteles, cuando eso no debería ocurrir.